# Positioning div, over another div, aligned - right

Tags: css

OK there is an image in a centered div, which is placed at the center of a page. Its width is 400px.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- to place another div - inside of that div with alignment right via CSS.

Due to various screen resolution, I wish to avoid commands "top:, right:".

How to achieve that?

```
<div class="non"><div class="info">Go top right</div><a href=""><img src="images/top.jpg"></a></div>
```

CSS..

```
.non { width:400px; background-color:#d20000;  }
.info { position:absolute;float:right; background-color:#efefef; }
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QhYS9/)

Comment: A picture, and your current code, would do wonders.

Comment: I have no CSS code since.. I'm expecting to write it after this answer :P

Comment: Great, and a representative picture..?

Comment: @ David - None. I'm writing code right now. "Position:absolute;" does it, but only if you wanna place div on a left. I just wanna make div to go right. And thats it.

Comment: @Xfile .. David and I mean, get a program like GIMP or Photoshop, and make a picture describing what you want to do.

Comment: OK guys there is a fiddle link up now, so hope it clears out this thing, thx :P

Comment: Just remove `position:absolute;`. It would be on top right over the `.non` division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this, it should work:

```
.non { width:400px; background-color:#d20000; position: relative; }
.info { position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; background-color:#efefef; }
```

I know you want to avoid using top and right, but if you do this, the .info class is positioned perfect top right corner of the .non class div, not the whole page :)

Comment: THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANX :DDDDDDD

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't really know how to do this save for `float: position` or `right: 0`.  I managed to achieve what you want using two positions..  `relative` of the containing div, and `absolute` of the inner div:

```css
.non {
    width:400px;
    background-color:#d20000;
    position: relative;
}
.info {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#efefef;
    right: 0;
}​
```

Other than that, as @HashemQolami has said, just remove the `position: absolute` from your code, and [it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/pfPvH/).